# Loop logic to store 2D array values in one liner vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

I have one requirement where I need to store 2 axis values into liner vector, some values like[x =0][y=1] and [y=0][x=1] i dint know how to save

I simply added i+j to find index but it now working in all case

I have 0>=x<=200 and 0>=y<=103

where x increment x= x+1
      y increment y = y+1.5

is there any generic formula i can derive to save all data linearly

Comment: C or C++? The answer for one language may not be appropriate for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector_1d_index = vector_2d_row_index * vector_2d_row_length + vector_2d_column_index
```

... assuming your 2D vector is i) row-major and ii) rectangular (uniform length rows).

(`vector_1d_size = vector_2d_row_count * vector_2d_row_length`).

Comment: 1*1.5+1 = 2.5 can we pass 2.5 as index value to vector

Comment: @Sijith why do you pass a *decimal* as an index? You should apply a scaling beforehand to convert the indices to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is vague. But what I can gather is that you are looking to store values from 2-d indices in a 1-d array. The general technique is to use something like follows:

Assume `row, col` are 2-d index coordinates

```
<1-d index> = <max number of columns> * row + col
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood right, you want a way to store a 2D float-indexed array in C++. You will need some conversion, because C++ "only support 1D arrays" (that isn't strictly true, but we will pretend that it is).

First we need to know the ranges and the increments. You provided them, and for X the range is `[0, 200]` and for Y `[0, 103]` with increments `1` and `1.5` respectvely.

That means we have `((200-0)/1) = 200` possible values for X and `((103-0)/1.5) = 68.666...` possible values for Y. We'll go with 69 possible values for Y.

So, we could have the following array:

```
int my_array_of_ints[69 * 200];
```

For example, the item `[X=0][Y=0]` will be our `[0 * 69 + 0]` index (item `my_array_of_ints[0]`), while our `[X=1][Y=1.5]` will be our `[1 * 69 + 1]` index (item `my_array_of_ints[70]`). Note that we can't have items with [Y=0.5] or [Y=1] because Y increment is fixed to 1.5 (i.e Y must be 0 or 1.5 or 3 or 4.5 or 6 or ...).

This function for converting the 2D index into a 1D linear index would be:

```
#include <cmath>

int get_element(float x, float y){
    int index_x = std::round(x / 1);
    int index_y = std::round(y / 1.5);
    if ((0 <= index_x) && (index_x < 200) &&
        (0 <= index_y) && (index_y < 69)){
        return my_array_of_ints[index_y * 200 + index_x];
    } else {
         // You should decide what to do if x or y is out-of-range
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Where:

- `1` is the increment of x
- `1.5` is the increment of y
- `200` is the number of possibles values of x in that range with this increment
- `69` is the number of possibles values of y in that range with this increment.

So then we could do something like this:

```
get_element(1, 1.5)
```

And it would return the value of `[X=1][Y=1.5]` inside `my_array_of_ints`.

Wrapping this code around a class, templatizing the type of the array, generalizing the ranges and increments and providing a dummy main:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Datatype> class Vector2D {
    float x_increment;
    float x_minimum;
    float x_maximum;

    float y_increment;
    float y_minimum;
    float y_maximum;

    // For example, Y range [0, 103] with increment 1.5
    // results in 69 possibles values for Y, and we need to
    // remember to "linearize" the indexes
    int x_possibles;
    int y_possibles;

    Datatype *array;
    public:
    Vector2D(float x_increment, float y_increment,
             float x_maximum, float y_maximum,
             float x_minimum=0, float y_minimum=0)
        : x_increment(x_increment), x_minimum(x_minimum),
          x_maximum(x_maximum), y_increment(y_increment),
          y_minimum(y_minimum), y_maximum(y_maximum),

          // These two may seem arcane, but they are the
          // generalization of how we found the values initially
          x_possibles(std::ceil((x_maximum-x_minimum)/x_increment)),
          y_possibles(std::ceil((y_maximum-y_minimum)/y_increment)),
          array(new Datatype[y_possibles * x_possibles]) {

        // This may help to understand this 2D Vector
        std::cout << "Creating 2D vector X in range ["
            << x_minimum << ", " << x_maximum
            << "] with increment of " << x_increment
            << " (totalizing " << x_possibles
            << " possible values for x) "
            << " and Y in range [" << y_minimum
            << ", " << y_maximum << "] with increment of "
            << y_increment << " (totalizing " << y_possibles
            << " values for y)."
            << std::endl;
    }

    // Frees up the raw array
    ~Vector2D(){
        delete this->array;
    }

    Datatype& get_element(float x, float y){
        int index_x = std::round((x-x_minimum)/this->x_increment);
        int index_y = std::round((y-y_minimum)/this->y_increment);

        // This debug message may help understand this function
        // It is, in some sense, the answer of this question
        std::cout << "The 2D point [X=" << x << ", Y=" << y
                  <<  "] is mapped into the vector index ["
                  << index_y << " * " << x_possibles
                  << " + " << index_x << "]" << std::endl;

        if ((0 <= index_x) && (index_x < x_possibles) &&
            (0 <= index_y) && (index_y < y_possibles)){
            return this->array[index_y * x_possibles + index_x];
        } else {
            // You should decide what to do if x or y is out-of-range
            return this->array[0];
        }
    }
};


int main(){
    // And you could use that class like this:

    // A 2D-like vector with X [0, 200] inc. 1
    // and Y [0, 103] inc. 1.5 of floats
    Vector2D<float> my_data(1, 1.5, 200, 103, 0, 0);

    // Sets [X=1][Y=1] to 0.61345
    my_data.get_element(1, 1) = 0.61345;

    auto elem1 = my_data.get_element(1, 1);
    // Prints the [X=1][Y=1] to screen
    std::cout << "[X=1][Y=1] is "
              << elem1
              << std::endl;

    // Gets a few more interesting points
    my_data.get_element(0, 0);
    my_data.get_element(1, 1.5);
    my_data.get_element(10, 15);
    my_data.get_element(200, 103);

    // A separator
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;

    // Another example, this time using chars
    // X is [-10, 1] inc. 0.1 and Y is [-5, 3] inc. 0.05
    Vector2D<char> my_chars(0.1, 0.05, 1, 3, -10, -5);

    // Sets [X=-4.3][Y=2.25] to '!'
    my_chars.get_element(-4.3, 2.25) = '!';

    auto elem2 = my_chars.get_element(-4.3, 2.25);
    std::cout << "[X=-4.3][Y=2.25] is "
              << elem2
              << std::endl;

}
```

Outputs:

```
Creating 2D vector X in range [0, 200] with increment of 1 (totalizing 200 possible values for x)  and Y in range [0, 103] with increment of 1.5 (totalizing 69 values for y).
The 2D point [X=1, Y=1] is mapped into the vector index [1 * 200 + 1]
The 2D point [X=1, Y=1] is mapped into the vector index [1 * 200 + 1]
[X=1][Y=1] is 0.61345
The 2D point [X=0, Y=0] is mapped into the vector index [0 * 200 + 0]
The 2D point [X=1, Y=1.5] is mapped into the vector index [1 * 200 + 1]
The 2D point [X=10, Y=15] is mapped into the vector index [10 * 200 + 10]
The 2D point [X=200, Y=103] is mapped into the vector index [69 * 200 + 200]
---
Creating 2D vector X in range [-10, 1] with increment of 0.1 (totalizing 110 possible values for x)  and Y in range [-5, 3] with increment of 0.05 (totalizing 160 values for y).
The 2D point [X=-4.3, Y=2.25] is mapped into the vector index [145 * 110 + 57]
The 2D point [X=-4.3, Y=2.25] is mapped into the vector index [145 * 110 + 57]
[X=-4.3][Y=2.25] is !
```

Hope that may help.